# javaagent error in tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Error:

```
 SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance 
 of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
 bean with name 
 'org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler#0': 
 Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
 bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested  
 \exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader  
 [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 
 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom 
 LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: 
 -javaagent:spring-agent.jar
```

But I have javaagent in my tomcat VM arguments

```
 -Dext.prop.dir="/home/gopi/Desktop/REST_CONFIG" -javaagent:/home/gopi/.m2
 /repository/org/springframework/spring-agent/2.5.6/spring-agent-
 2.5.6.jar -Dcatalina.base="/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62" 
 -Dcatalina.home="/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.62" -Dwtp.deploy="/opt/apache-
  tomcat-7.0.62/wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="/opt/apache-tomcat-
  7.0.62/endorsed"
```

`-Dext.prop.dir and -javaagent` added by me and remaining are by default.. How do i solve this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: it's `-Djavaagent...` I guess. Weird setting though, never seen it before.

Comment: No jan. It's -javaagent only

Comment: Crap, you're right. :)

Comment: Another guess (don't trust my guesses too much) - try quotation marks around the path.

Comment: better update your question instead of commenting.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to give below to specify which loadTimeWeaver to use. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-environments) for details.

```
 <context:load-time-weaver
            weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver"/>

</beans>
```